# Get items from a document library where File Size=1KB and it has certain document version

Tags: 2010, document-library, powershell

I want to get items from a document library where File Size=1KB and it has certain document version 2.0 below script.I created but how can I enhance it?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://application url
$list = $web.Lists["CsFarms"]
$items = $list.Items
foreach ($item in $items) | where {$_['File Size'] -eq 1KB}
{
    $file = $item.File
    $fileVersions = $file.Versions      
    if ($fileVersions = 2.0)
    {           


    }   
}
```

my requirement is i want to check for if any document has more than two versions i want restore from its version number 2.0

[image]

Comment: Is this script working?

Comment: no please check the image i want to restore every document that has v2.0 and some documents i want to skip that has only one version and size of documents is more than 1 KB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script, you can use the $xml.row.ows_FileSizeDisplay to check file size.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://application url
$list = $web.Lists["CsFarms"]
$items = $list.Items

foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $file = $item.File
    $fileVersions = $file.Versions   
    $xml = [xml]$item.xml
       $filesize = $xml.row.ows_FileSizeDisplay
    if ($fileVersions.Count -gt 1 -and (([int]$filesize)/1024) -eq 1)
    {           
           $fileVersions.RestoreByLabel(2.0) 
    }   
}
```

Comment: hi i want to check file size=1kb

Comment: @adilahmed, just switch -gt to -eq 1.

Comment: hi my requirement is i want to check for if any document has more than two versions i want restore from its version number 2.0

Comment: $fileVersions it returns all documents and i can not able to  restore version number 2.0  $fileVersions.Restore(2.0)

Comment: try this $fileVersions.RestoreByLabel(2.0)

Comment: also check there was $fileVersions = 2.0, if you want comparison use -eq for equal.